# how to handle List object inside an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a class:

```
public class Kit
{
    private int _CK_ID = 0;
    private String _CK_Title = "";
    private String _CK_Description = "";

    public int CK_ID
    {
        get { return _CK_ID; }
        set { _CK_ID = value; }
    }

    public String CK_Title
    {
        get { return _CK_Title; }
        set { _CK_Title = value; }
    }

    public String CK_Description
    {
        get { return _CK_Description; }
        set { _CK_Description = value; }
    }

}
```

Each kit can have a list of images.

Is it a smart thing to put inside the class a `List<Images>`?

If yes, how can I call the images when I bind the `List<Kit>` to a `Repeater` to call the other properties?  I use `<%# Eval("CK_Title")%>`, for example.  How to loop all images?

Comment: You can use repeater's `ItemDataBound` event to bind the nested repeater with the images. You just have to cast `e.Item.DataItem` to `Kit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand you, it seems straighforward: define a `List` and expose the property:

```
private List<SomeType> underlyingSomeList;

public List<SomeType> SomeList { get { return underlyingList; } }
```

As for accessing the entries, you can bind the property itself to a `Repeater` and in the `ItemDataBound` event handler get the individual thing with `var thing = e.Item.DataItem as SomeThing`, and go from there, using `FindControl` to gain access to elements and populate with the item's data.

Answer (score 4):

Nest another repeater inside your repeater, and bind the `List` object to it on the `ItemDataBound` event.

*Repeater Example*:

```
<asp:repeater id="rep" runat="server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <h2><%# Eval("CK_Title")%></h2>
      <asp:repeater id="imagerep" runat="server">
         <itemtemplate>
             <img src="<%# Eval("URL")%>" />
         </itemtemplate>
      </asp:repeater>
   </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```